# if-else-else if

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and i am doing some practiceit questions to brush up on my java skills.

Write a method named season that takes two integers as parameters representing a month and day and that returns a String indicating the season for that month and day. Assume that months are specified as an integer between 1 and 12 (1 for January, 2 for February, and so on) and that the day of the month is a number between 1 and 31.

If the date falls between 12/16 and 3/15, you should return "Winter". If the date falls between 3/16 and 6/15, you should return "Spring". If the date falls between 6/16 and 9/15, you should return "Summer". And if the date falls between 9/16 and 12/15, you should return "Fall".

```
public static String season(int month,int day){
   
    if(month>=9 && month<=12 && day==15||day==16){
        return "Fall";
    }
    else if (month>=4 && month<=6 && day==16||day==15){
       return "Spring";
     }
    else if (month>=6 && month<=9 && day==16||day==15){
         return "Summer";
     }
     else {
          return"Winter";

         
      }

  
}
```

But i'm not getting the output.But it seems right to me.Anyone can tell me where did i go wrong?

Comment: Should `month==4` be `month>=4`?

Comment: In the second if `month<=6`is useless because you are testing `month==4`

Comment: Your conditions are wrong. Eg:
Applying for october second, which is Fall, you get winter.

Comment: The problem is that with your code, no matter what month is, if `day==16` it will always return `fall`.

Answer (score 8):

[`||` has lower precendence than `&&`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and your conditions don't look correct - you probably wanted to write something like:

```
if((month == 9 && day >= 16) //September, on or after the 16th
      || month == 10         //or October
      || month == 11         //or November
      || (month == 12 && day <=15)) { //or December, but before or on the 15th
    return "Fall";
}
```

(same comment for the other conditions)

---

You could make it shorter by using a little hack, but readability is maybe not as good (debatable):

```
int mdd = month * 100 + day; //date in MDD format, for example 507 for May 7th

if (mdd >= 916 && mdd <= 1215) {
    return "Fall";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that only 9/15, 9/16, 12/15 and 12/16 were the winter though?

Comment: One question.I realise the day part keep repeating.So is there any way to store it?

Answer (score 3):

You should try to write something like this:

```
if((month>9 && month<12) || (month==9 && day>=16) || (month==12 && day<=15)){
    return "Fall";
} else if 
    ...
}
```

The precedences are important, also, but you have to think over what you really want to achieve, and build your expression according to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(month>=9 && month<=12 && (day==15||day==16)){
    return "Fall";
}
```

This issue with this is that only the 15th and 16th of months 9-12 are considered the winter.

**Solution**

If it were up to me, I would re-factor the if-else tree to first check for months, then check the days. So for example:

```
if(month>=9 && month<=12)
{
    // Some special cases. 
    if((month == 9 && day < 15) || (month == 12 && day > 16))
    {
        // It isn't fall.
    }
    else
    {
        // It is fall.
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the `2000` club :)

Answer (score 0):

This runs just fine. You had some minow mistakes I corrected

```
public static String season(int month,int day){

   if((month>=9 && month<=12) && (day==15||day==16))
       return "Fall";    
   else{ 
       if ((month>=4 && month<=6) && (day==16||day==15))
           return "Spring";        
       else{
           if ((month>=6 && month<=9) && (day==16||day==15))
               return "Summer";    
           else 
               return"Winter";
       }
   }
```

}